# g++ : include problems when cross compiling

Tags: include, embedded, g++, mips, cross-compiling

I've got a problem that's a bit strange.
We have a project that we compile for several different architectures, notably these 2: SH4 and MIPS.

We've had a problem for some time, where some code would compile in SH4, but not for MIPS, because of missing includes. I've narrowed down the problem to this test file:

```
#include <sstream>
// deliberately not including the needed includes

int main()
{
  const char *toto = "Hello World";
  // using printf and strlen which require <stdio.h> and <string.h>
  printf("Toto has len %d\n", strlen(toto)); 
  return 0;
}
```

---

#### Compiling to SH4 with this command

```
$ sh4-linux-g++ -O0 -g -Wall -Werror -Wno-write-strings \
                -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions test.cpp -o test
$
```

-> no problem at all. The file actually executes normally.

---

#### Whereas with MIPS

```
$ mips-linux-gnu-g++ -O0 -g -Wall -Werror -Wno-write-strings \
                     -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions test.cpp -o test 
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:6: error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope
$
```

---

Now, I've run several things, notably the dependency generation of both g++. What I see is this:

#### SH4

```
$ sh4-linux-g++ -O0 -g -Wall -Werror -Wno-write-strings \ 
                -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions test.cpp -M |grep "/string.h"

  /opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/target/usr/include/string.h \
```

-> string.h automatically included.

#### MIPS

```
mips-linux-gnu-g++ -O0 -g -Wall -Werror -Wno-write-strings \
 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions test.cpp -M |grep "/string.h"
```

-> string.h missing in includes

For information:

```
SH4 version  = 4.2.4 (2007)  
MIPS version = 4.3.2 (2008)
```

What's going on here? The `<sstream>` include seems to drag along all what's needed for strlen() when compiling on SH4, whereas on MIPS it doesn't. I suspect this is because the versions are different, but I'm not sure.

My real problem, in the end, is that when I develop on SH4, I'd like to be sure that if it *compiles*, it will compile on all targets.
Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I think the only solution is to have sufficient self-discipline when coding to ensure that all required headers are explicitly #included and never rely on side-effects of other #includes. In the above case you should have `#include <cstdio>` and `#include <cstring>` and not rely on the side effects of `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I guess would be the solution, but this example above is simply what I got from stripping the actual faulty file. We have a continuous integration process that tells us when a compilation fails. But I guess human fault is always going to happen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's going on here?

You're basically asking "why does my non-standard code compile with one version of a compiler but not another?"  Of course it's because the versions are different.

See the [GCC 4.3 changes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) which say this under the **Runtime Library (libstdc++)** section:

> Header dependencies have been streamlined, reducing unnecessary includes and pre-processed bloat.

We've continued reducing header dependencies in more recent versions too, to be stricter and to reduce namespace pollution (e.g. [4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html#cplusplus) avoids including `<cstddef>` unnecessarily, and [4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html) no longer includes `<unistd.h>` unnecessarily), so to answer your final question I would suggest using the most recent GCC version you can (even if only to check the code not for production builds) as it has the strictest, cleanest headers and will find the most problems.  Another option would be to use an even stricter standard library implementation, such as [libcomo](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/libcomo/).

Comment: That's actually the kind of answer I was looking for. I wasn't sure if the header includes beiing different from one version to another was normal. So, yeah, we'll have to isolate the code that can compile on x86 and add this architecture to the continuous integration. Thanks!